# Uniform distribution probability?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, uniform-distribution

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, each of which is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$. Find the probability that $(X−1/2)^2+(Y−1/2)^2≤1/9$. Give at least $8$ correct digits after the decimal point.

I do not know where to start with this question. Can someone please get me on the right track?

Comment: Why do you need 8 rather than say 6 digits? Why do you need any digits of imprecision? P.S. There is a special tag called `homework` for homework questions.

Comment: Algebraically, $(X-1/2)2+(Y-1/2)2\le 1/9$ is equivalent to $X+Y\le 19/18$, which is a considerably simpler expression. Perhaps you did not write what you intended? Maybe it should be  $(X-1/2)^2+(Y-1/2)^2\le 1/9$? In either case, *draw a picture* of the set of $(X,Y)$ that satisfy the inequality. Then think about how you would find the probability of that set, given that $(X,Y)$ has a constant density.

Comment: I did mean to have (X−1/2)^2+(Y−1/2)^2 ≤ 1/9, sorry. Algebraically, I understand that if there was only one distribution, instead of two added together, then the probability would be 2/3. How would I factor in the second distribution?

Comment: Re the self-study tag:  the exact same question has just been posed an hour ago by a different person at:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775525/probability-of-independent-random-variables   ... Except they list it as their HOMEWORK ... And you are self-studying the exact same question???  Should SE be a homework factory??

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you draw a picture? Here's a hint:

[image: Hint]

Comment: Fantastic answer; it shortcuts the whole issue down to a single very clear diagram from which the algebraic answer is instantly obvious, and the approach ('*draw a picture*') is a very useful one on a large variety of problems.

Comment: @baudolino  Pretty picture - what software do you use?

Comment: @wolfies: Geogebra. It's open source and pretty cool.

Comment: @baudolino Cool - many thanks. I will take a look.